# Java split list based on element

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

So I've got a class `Standard` with properties and constructor:

```
String studentName;
String category;

Standard(studentName, category)
```

I've also got a `List` of `Standard` objects like so:

```
[S1,S2,S3,S4]
```

where

```
S1 = Standard("ABC","1");
S2 = Standard("DEF","2")
S3 = Standard("IJK","1")
S4 = Standard("LMN","2")
```

I would like to group `Standard` objects with same `category` into a `Map(String,List<Standard>)` with key as `category` and value as `List` of `Standard` objects like so:

```
Map<String,List<Standard>> m = {1=[S1, S3], 2=[S2,S4]};
```

Now I would like to know whether this can be done using Java 8 streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector:

```
Map<String, List<Standard>> map = standards.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Standard::getCategory));
```

Assuming you have `getCategory` method implemented.